# Packer - load exe without relocation

Tags: operating-system, exe, portable-executable, relocation

I'm trying to get a good understanding of the PE format by writing a simple exe packer.

My first step was to write an exe loader which would take an exe file as a argument and would load it in its address space. 
My problem is that many exe don't have base relocation tables because they expect to be loaded at their prefered imagebase address. In the case of my loader (and later, of the simple packer I imagined), the loader is already loaded at 0x400000 which forces the original exe to be loaded at another address (therefore needing relocations).

I tried to take a look at how UPX was doing it but I got lost in the source code.

One solution I can see, is to relocate the unpacker (or the loader) to make it load at an address that would leave the prefered exe imagebase address available to avoid any later relocations but it seems a bit complicated.

Is there any other way?

How does UPX do it?

Is it possible to rebuild the base relocation table of an exe?

Best regards,
Maxime

Comment: Have you tried executing the exe? On x64 I don't think those fixups are necessary. As far as I know MSVS produces images that either contain RVAs or RIP relative addresses so no need for relocations.